# __doPostBack() is not fired when having dropdown selectedindex is same

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, dopostback

I have two dropdown ddlCountry and ddlState and one button Submit.
While ddlstate is in update panel.
On submit of button value of both dropdown store in database.
And I show the data in Repeater Control.(In HTML Table structure)
ASPX CODE

```
<table id="tablelist" class="csstablelist" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="csstablelisttoptr">
                            ddlCountryID
                        </td>
                        <td class="csstablelisttoptr">
                            ddlCountryText
                        </td>
                        <td class="csstablelisttoptr">
                            ddlstateText
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeaterList_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr onclick="selectRow(this);">
                                <td class="csstablelisttd" style="display: none">
                                    <asp:Label ID="ddlCountryID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ddlCountryID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="csstablelisttd">
                                    <asp:Label ID="ddlCountryText" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ddlCountryText")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="csstablelisttd">
                                    <asp:Label ID="ddlstateText" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ddlstateText")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </table>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" CssClass="csstextbox" Width="207px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelState" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState " runat="server" CssClass="csstextbox" Width="177px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Width="80px" OnClientClick="return validateForm();" Text="Save" CssClass="cssbutton" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />


ddlCountryID | ddlCountryText | ddlstateText
1            | USA            | XYZ
2            |India           | PQR
```

Onclick of TR i write below (SelectRow(this)) function in javascript for highliting the repeater value and dropdown value match and getting selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectRow(objTR)
{
 var ddlCountry =document.getElementById('<%=ddlCountry.ClientID %>');
 var ddlState =document.getElementById('<%=ddlState .ClientID %>');

    for (i = 0; i < ddlCountry .options.length; i++)
    {
        if (ddlCountry .options[i].text == objTR.cells[1].innerText.trim())
            break;
    }           
    ddlCountry .options[i].selected = true;

    __doPostBack(ddlCountry .id, objTR.cells[2].innerText.trim());    
}
</script>
```

I write ddlCountry SelectedIndexChangedEvent In code behind.

From Javascript I am firing __doPostBack() and passing ddlCountry as event target ddlStateText as event argument to SelectedIndexChangedEvent and getting value in event like this.

```
string stateDescription = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
ddlState .Items.FindByText(stateDescription ).Selected = true;//for highliting the repeater value and dropdown value match and selected
```

Binding Country on pageLoad

```
 if(!Ispostback)
protected Void BindCountry()

{

strSQL = @"SELECT countryID,Country from Country_Master";
        DataTable dataTableCountry = null;
        dataTableCountry = objSqlDbComm.ExecuteDatasetQuery(strSQL).Tables[0];

        int countryID;
                string Country;     
        var dictioneryCountry = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        foreach(DataRow dr in dataTableCountry.Rows)
        {
            countryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["countryID"]);
            Country= dr["Country"].ToString();          
            dictioneryCountry.Add(countryID,Country);
        }
        ddlCountry.Items.Clear();
        ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Value";
        ddlCountry.DataValueField = "Key";
        ddlCountry.DataSource = dictioneryCountry;
        ddlCountry.DataBind();
        ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("[Select]", "-1"));
        ddlCountry.Items[0].Selected = true;
}
```

My problem is if I have following repeater data.

```
ddlCountryID | ddlCountryText | ddlstateText
1            | USA            | XYZ
2            |India           | PQR
2            |India           | MNO
```

When I select row number 3 that have country india and state mno then __dopostback() method is fire.

When I goes to row number 1 then __dopostback() method is fire.

When I come from row nuber 1 to 3 then method is fire correct way but when goes from row nuber 3 to 2 having country id same __dopostback() method is not fire and state is not selected from ddlstate.

Comment: how you are binding ddlCountry?

Comment: i ma binding ddlCountry only in !ispostback{BindCountry();}

Comment: why should it trigger if you didn't change anything?

Comment: only i have to display repeater data value to their respective dropdownlist.

Comment: If you accepted Itison's answer, then why you didnt give that Bounty point to him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you debug your code, you will see that __doPostBack() is indeed working because the code in Page_Load is being executed (try setting a breakpoint here to check). The issue is that the index of your DropDownList is not changing, therefore the IndexChanged event is not fired and ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged never runs. When you call __doPostBack(), this not the same as manually calling ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged from the codebehind.

Is there a particular reason that you would be doing a post back other than to set this dropdown list value?

**SOLUTION 1**

I would advise removing the __doPostBack() line and adding the following instead:

```
var state = objTR.cells[2].innerText.trim();
for (var i = 0; i < ddlState.options.length; i++)
{
    if (ddlState.options[i].text == state)
    {
        ddlState.options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Alternatively, if you really have to post back, you could do the following:

a. Add a hidden button inside of your update panel like this:

```
<div style="display: none">
<asp:Button ID="btnState" OnClick="btnState_Click" runat="server" />
</div>
```

b. Change your javascript to do the following after selecting the country:

```
document.getElementById('__EVENTARGUMENT').value = objTR.cells[2].innerText.trim();
document.getElementById('<%= btnState.ClientID %>').click();
```

c. Create a FilterState() function and call this from your ddlcountry indexchanged event

```
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilterState();
}

private void FilterState()
{
// insert whatever filtering code you had here
}
```

d. Add your btnState_Click function (note that the way you were setting the selected item of ddlState before would throw an error if an item was already selected.):

```
protected void btnState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilterState();
    string state = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    if (state != "")
        ddlState.SelectedValue = state;
}
```

**SOLUTION 3**

A third solution would allow you to still use __doPostBack, and scrap the SelectedIndexChanged event altogether by putting this in the Page_Load function:

```
if (IsPostBack && Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == ddlCountry.UniqueID)
{
    FilterState();
    string stateDescription = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    if (stateDescription != "")
        ddlState.SelectedValue = stateDescription;
}
```

On another note, for your BindCountry function there's no real reason to use a Dictionary, you can just bind the DataTable directly:

```
strSQL = @"SELECT countryID,Country from Country_Master";
DataTable dataTableCountry = objSqlDbComm.ExecuteDatasetQuery(strSQL).Tables[0];
ddlCountry.Items.Clear();
ddlCountry.DataSource = dataTableCountry;
ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataValueField = "countryID";
ddlCountry.DataBind();
ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("[Select]", "-1"));
ddlCountry.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: ya there is particular reason i m using dopostback.I will give u explnation i am selecting country from repeater data if i select country USA then i filter its state on ddlCountryselect event.and highlight the matching state in dropdown which is present in repeater state coloumn.  Ya its true DropDownList is not changing, therefore the IndexChanged event is not fired  but is there any way making functionality correct doing dopostback.(if we refresh DOM then its possible)

Comment: Well my second solution involved doing a postback with the button which has the same effect. I've modified it so that the filtering is done whether it's from selecting a different country or clicking a row in the repeater control. Otherwise, no, you can't really use __doPostBack on a DropDownList control and have it execute SelectedIndexChanged event without the index actually changing. There are always workarounds you can do for this, but it's totally unnecessary and anyone looking at your code will probably be confused. It's not practical to use SelectedIndexChanged when it isn't changing.

Comment: but i have to fire only dopostback from javascript when user selects country from repeter date even dropdownlist index is same .Yes there is a solution even when dropdownlistindex is same.i research lot but not find anything.(ur second option on button click event is good)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You said the second option is good, but it sounds like you still don't find it acceptable. What does it not allow you to accomplish? Why do you want to use a solution involving dopostback on ddlCountry so badly? It seems really arbitrary.

Comment: ltison:thanks for ur reply i m straight forward tell me can we do my functionality  using dopostback even dropdown index is same (Yes or No).i have to find solution why we cant using dopostback for same dropdown index.i will accept u answer if i got reason proper

Comment: Yes, there's one other thing you could do. I edited my answer to make it a bit easier to differentiate the different solutions. See solution #3. As previously mentioned, if you call __doPostBack it still posts back whether the index changes or not. If it doesn't change, the SelectedIndexChanged event doesn't fire... so you'd have to move your code to Page_Load. In my opinion it's a bit odd to use __doPostBack for this in the first place, but this will work.

Comment: In second solution why FilterState();
call two times

Comment: Because btnState_Click and ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged are never run on the same postback. I just included a call to FilterState() in ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged because you said that you filter the state when you change the country. The main idea of the solution is that the filtering/selecting of the state is done in btnState_Click.

Comment: if i remove FilterState() in ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged then it gets error multiple select value in ddlstate

Comment: Yes, you have to change "ddlState .Items.FindByText(stateDescription ).Selected = true;" to "ddlState.SelectedValue = stateDescription;". I mentioned this in solution 2, part d.

Comment: solution 2 is perfect but having one disadvantage FilterState(); is execute two times

Comment: It isn't executed twice. When you choose a different country, it executes once in ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged. When you click a row in the repeater it executes once in btnState_Click. These do not happen at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

This may be because you are not binding separate Value for dropdownlist for Text = "India", thus server is not recognizing that the value is changed and thus not processing selectedindexchanged event.

Try to create a datasouce that has different value for both the India text or just use one India Text

I can clearly see that there are two duplicate reocords in listview for India with duplicate key (2)

This is not recommended. use only one record that should have unique key.

I can understand you have only one data source thus modify your code in such a way that while adding items to the ddlCountry check if that already exists or not if exists just don't add it again. replace the followign code in your Bindcontry code and it should work fine.

```
    foreach(DataRow dr in dataTableCountry.Rows)
    {
        countryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["countryID"]);
        Country= dr["Country"].ToString();

        if ( ! dictioneryCountry.Contains(countryID))
        {
           dictioneryCountry.Add(countryID,Country);
        }
    }
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: i m binding ddlCountry only once on page load !ispostback{BindCountry();}

Comment: Thanks for reply..No matter what i show in repeater data.Ya its always two or number of state for one country. i am firing selectedindexchanged event from javascript..And also i have used ur code but no works..

Comment: BindCountry(); method fire when first time page loads not for every postback